# Stop support of a NuGet package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

How to gracefully stop support of NuGet package in nuget.org repository? Actually I moved the package to another NuGet channel (e.g. moved https://www.nuget.org/packages/my_old_package/ to https://www.nuget.org/packages/my_new_package/). And want to notify existing subscribers that they should switch.

Currently, I consider the following solutions:

1. Publish last build with description like "This package is no longer
   supported. Switch to other package..."
2. Simply delete package - not sure how will it affect customers.

What approach can you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [unlist the old NuGet package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/deleting-packages) so it will not be found when searching for packages. Unlisting is what happens when you delete the package either from the command line using NuGet.exe or from the gallery on nuget.org.

With the NuGet package being unlisted existing users can still use that package. Restoring the package will still work since the NuGet package still exists.

Notifying existing users of the NuGet package not being supported is not a feature of NuGet. If you need that you would have to implement yourself. For example, you could add a readme.txt to the latest NuGet package which informs the user that this package is now deprecated and they should be using a different NuGet package. The readme.txt will automatically be opened by Visual Studio when the package installed. The only problem here is that this approach is incompatible with unlisting the NuGet package. The NuGet package with the readme.txt would still need to be listed on nuget.org.

Another approach, which may or may not be a possibility, is to have your old NuGet package simply install the other NuGet package. So the old NuGet package has no content itself but just has a dependency on the other NuGet package.

Of these approaches I think I would just unlist all the versions of the old NuGet package. You could also update the package description on nuget.org by editing the metadata directly on the site to indicate the old NuGet package is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer!